# Getting undefined method `gsub' for 6:Fixnum (Rails) in a view with jQuery + ERB?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to add some jQuery + ERB to a specific view:

**views/posts/show.html.erb (top of the file):**

```
<% content_for :javascript do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".post-<%=@post.id%> h3").prepend('<%=escape_javascript @post.votes.count %>');
  </script>
<% end %>

<h2>posts show</h2>

(etc...)

<div class="post-<%=@post.id%>">
  <h3>votes</h3><br />
  <%= link_to "Vote Up", vote_up_path(@post), :remote => true %><br />
</div>
```

**views/layouts/application.html.erb (bottom of the file):**

```
(etc...)

</div>

<%= yield %>

<%= yield :javascript %>
</body>

</html>
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
undefined method `gsub' for 6:Fixnum
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <% content_for :javascript do %>
2:   <script type="text/javascript">
3:     $("post-<%=@post.id%>").html('<%=escape_javascript @post.votes.count %>');
4:   </script>
5: <% end %>
```

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) calls [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) on whatever you pass it, which doesn't make sense for a number. You can either not call `escape_javascript` or give it a String instead:

```
$("post-<%=@post.id%>").html('<%=escape_javascript @post.votes.count.to_s %>');
```

Answer (score 3):

Since `@post.votes.count` is (presumably) simply an integer value, you can just use `to_json`:

```
$(".post-<%= @post.id %> h3").prepend(<%= @post.votes.count.to_json %>);
```

Notice that you don't need to wrap the `<%= %>` expression in quotes since `to_json` will do that for you when necessary.