# Rails render format js with unique ids

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<div id="contact_form_<%= i %>"></div>
```

I have an id inside each loop. I want to render a form on each of these ids.

```
$("#contact_form").html("<%= j(render 'form') %>");
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to render a form with unique ids. I tried `$("#contact_form<%= i %>")` but javascript doesn't take erb tags. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: is it different form or same for all?

Comment: its different ids for all

Comment: what i asked if you update all the rows together or one at time? because if you update all together just use wildcard of id, if it one by one you need to pass the index on action and then use it in the AJAX call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If* you're rendering your code inside a `js.erb` template (IE `app/views/controller/action.js.erb`), you can pass as much `ERB` as you want:

```
<% @ids.each do |i| %>
   $("#contact_form_<%=j i %>").html("<%= j(render 'form') %>");
<% end %>
```

If you have multiple forms with different `ids`, why not just pass them to the `form` partial:

```
#app/views/controller/action.js.erb
<%= render "form", collection: @ids, as: :id %>

#app/views/controller/_form.html.erb
<%= content_tag :div, id: "contact_form_#{id}" do %>
   <%= form_tag [[url]], id: id do %>
      ...
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9155431/getting-undefined-method-gsub-for-6fixnum-rails-in-a-view-with-jquery-erb helped too